# How to use dplyr with a vector of arguments

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to take a data frame that has various groups and to find which groups share a common value or *set* of values.

For example, suppose that I have some fruit baskets with different fruits and I want to find out which baskets have a particular fruit in them.

Here's my fruit basket:

```
fruit_baskets <- data.frame(basket=c(rep("blue",3),rep("red",3),rep("green",3)),
                        fruits=c("orange", "tomato", "pear", 
                                 "orange", "tomato", "grape",
                                 "strawberry", "tomato", "grape"))
# > print(fruit_baskets)
#   basket     fruits
# 1   blue     orange
# 2   blue     tomato
# 3   blue       pear
# 4    red     orange
# 5    red     tomato
# 6    red      grape
# 7  green strawberry
# 8  green     tomato
# 9  green      grape
```

and my function to find which baskets contain a particular fruit:

```
find_similar_baskets_1 <- function(some_baskets, fruit) {
  some_baskets %>% 
    group_by(basket) %>% 
    summarise(xxx_1=max(ifelse(fruits==fruit, 1, 0))) %>% 
    filter(xxx_1 == 1) %>% 
    .[[1]] %>% unique %>% as.character
}
```

I can use this function to find baskets with a tomato.

```
> find_similar_baskets_1(fruit_baskets, "tomato")
[1] "blue"  "green" "red"
```

Likewise, I can create a function that finds which baskets both have **two** fruits.

```
find_similar_baskets_2 <- function(some_baskets, fruit_1, fruit_2) {
  some_baskets %>% 
  group_by(basket) %>% 
  summarise(xxx_1=max(ifelse(fruits==fruit_1, 1, 0)),
            xxx_2=max(ifelse(fruits==fruit_2, 1, 0))) %>% 
  filter(xxx_1 == 1 & xxx_2 == 1) %>% 
  .[[1]] %>% unique %>% as.character
}
```

Now I can use this function to find which baskets have an orange and a tomato (the blue and red one) and which baskets have a tomato and a grape (the green and red one).

```
find_similar_baskets_2(fruit_baskets, "orange", "tomato")
#[1] "blue" "red" 

find_similar_baskets_2(fruit_baskets, "tomato", "grape")
#[1] "green" "red"
```

In the ideal world, I'd be able to create a single function that does not depend on the number of values (i.e., fruits) that I give it.

```
find_similar_groups <- function(df, group_column, value_column, value_vector)
```

where I could have an arbitrarily large vector of values and where the group column (in this case "basket") and the value column ("fruits") aren't in the function.

```
df = fruit_baskets
column = "fruits"
values = c("tomato")  or c("orange", "tomato")
```

Comment: Regarding your `max` of an `ifelse`, you want to use `any`, like `fruit_baskets %>% group_by(basket) %>% filter(any(fruits=='tomato')) %>% .$basket %>% unique %>% as.character`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another way:

```
select_baskets_having_fruit <- function(bs,...){
    fs <- c(...)
    bs %>% 
        select_(basket, fruits) %>%
        group_by(basket) %>%
        filter(all(fs %in% fruits)) %>%
        .$basket %>% unique %>% as.character
}
```

And some examples:

```
fruit_baskets %>% select_baskets_having_fruit('tomato') 
# "blue"  "red"   "green"

fruit_baskets %>% select_baskets_having_fruit('orange','tomato') 
# "blue" "red"

fruit_baskets %>% select_baskets_having_fruit('tomato','grape') 
# "red"   "green"
```

---

**Generalization** To apply this to other grouping and selecting variables...

```
select_grp_with_x <- function(dat,...,g="basket",x="fruits"){
    xs <- c(...)
    dat %>% 
        select_(g,x) %>%
        group_by_(g) %>%
        filter(all(xs %in% .[[x]])) %>%
        .[[g]] %>% unique %>% as.character
}

fruit_baskets %>% select_grp_with_x('orange','tomato')
```

`dplyr` is not well suited to making generalized functions in my opinion, since you have to resort to constructs like `.[[]]` and underscore functions, like `select_`.

I prefer, for example

```
library(magrittr)
select_grp_with_x2 <- function(dat,...,g,x)
    split(dat[[x]], dat[[g]]) %>% 
        sapply( function(z) all(c(...) %in% z) ) %>% 
        which %>% names

select_grp_with_x2(fruit_baskets,'orange','tomato',g='basket',x='fruits') # "blue" "red"
```

With an understanding of base R, this is easier to read than the dplyr way, I think. However, if you're designing a function for efficiency (running fast without eating memory), you'll probably want to use an entirely different approach.

Comment: Thanks Frank for this answer and the suggestion to use any instead of max(ifelse()). I had meant to also ask about how to specify the "fruits" and "basket" as arguments rather than variables within the function (I updated the question).

Comment: @dchandler I have extended to that case. It should work if you pass `g` and `x` as alternatives to `basket` and `fruit`. I am still editing to add a further comment.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one answer, which takes a list of fruit as an input:

```
library(dplyr)
findbaskets <- function(df, fruitlist){
  x <- df %>% group_by(basket) %>%
              summarise(subset = all(fruitlist %in% fruits))
  x$basket[x$subset]
}
findbaskets(fruit_baskets, list("orange", "grape"))
[1] red
```

If you want to see if it contains `all` listed fruits, use the above, if you want any, change the `all` to `any`.

Comment: How would you modify it though so that the "fruits" and "basket" variables don't need to go inside the function and can be chosen arbitrarily?

Comment: You want [non-standard evaluation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html).